# switch statement: is layout visible versus is tab selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

So I am using a custom `dialog fragment`, when it pops up it asks a question and when the positive response "yes" is selected I want to load a specific `fragment` based on which `ActionTab` is selected. Obviously right now the code just loads 1 default `fragment` but I would be implementing a switch statement that checked either which `Tab` was selected or which `fragment` was currently visible. My question is there a preferred `method` for doing this? As in selecting `.isVisible()` for the `fragment`, or using the `.getSelectedTab()` `method` for the current `ActionTab`.

Here is my code, and thank you in advance for your time

**current .java**

```
public class StoreDialog_Fragment extends DialogFragment {
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder storeD = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    storeD.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_dialog, null))
            .setMessage(R.string.store_question)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes_q,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                               
                            // switch statement here
                            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                            ft.replace(R.id.header_fragment_container,
                                    new Assets_Fragment());
                            ft.commit();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_q,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // No it isn't!
                        }
                    });
    // Create the Dialog object and return it
    return storeD.create();
}
}
```

Comment: isVisible() is for when you are physically removing a view that you may not need anymore until later.  So you would be better off checking against the selected tab.

Comment: that makes sense, I guess the next question I need to figure out is how I would call the ActionBar from the parent activity and get the selected Tab. Any advice? =). Also feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept, a little sample wouldn't offend me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isVisible()` is for when you are physically removing a view that you may not need anymore until later; tied to View.Visible, View.Invisible, View.Gone. So you would be better off checking against the selected tab for what you are doing.

Additionally, as per your request you can simply find the ActionBar from the Activity easy enough and make small modifications like the following as per your followup question:

```
actionBar_ = getActionBar();
            actionBar_.setSubtitle("subtitle");
            actionBar_.setTitle("title");
            actionBar_.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);//If navigation from home needed
            actionBar_.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#BB000000")));  //Allow for some transparency in the ActionBar.
```

Comment: thanks buddy. I may be mistaken but wont that code instantiate an entirely new ActionBar? I already have one in existence, I merely wanted to call it from the parent Activity.

Comment: you are not creating a new one, you are grabbing the one that exists in your application.  You typically have to instantiate a new ActionBar and set it yourself with the new protocol and use a setter to replace existing components; but I want say always.